# MVC Search Filter by letter

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to make paging/filtering by first letter but I have a little problem. I tried to do this the easiest way possible and added this to controller:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(letterString))
            {
                anime = anime.Where(s => s.TITLE_OR.ToUpper().StartsWith(searchString.ToUpper())
                                       || s.TITLE_EN.ToUpper().StartsWith(searchString.ToUpper()));
            }
```

and in view do something like this:

```
<table>
<tr>
    @Html.ActionLink("All", "Index", new { letterString = "" })
</tr>
<tr>
    @Html.ActionLink("0-9", "Index", new { letterString = ??? })
</tr>
<tr>
    @Html.ActionLink("A", "Index", new { letterString = "A" })
</tr>
<tr>
    @Html.ActionLink("B", "Index", new { letterString = "B" })
</tr>
```

For letters it works perfect but I don't know how to make numbers. Is there any easy way to do this or I must do this differently?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what you mean, but if you want to find if letterstring is a number try this

```
public static bool VerifyInputIsNumber(string str)
        {
            double num;
            bool isInputANumber = double.TryParse(str, out num);
            return isInputANumber;
        }
```

Then in controller use this

```
 var isInt = IsInputANumber.VerifyInputIsNumber(str);

                    if (isInt)
{
is number so do somthing with it
}
```

Hope it helps

George